# Python - adding a script to select all pdf files

Tags: python, pdf, bulk, stamp

I am trying to bulk stamp a number of pdf files, I found something on github that does something very similar but you have to name each file within the script to match with the actual pdf file for it to work.

https://github.com/iprapas/pythonpdf

```
def stamp_pdf(input_path, stamp_path, output_path, add_frame=False):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    create_pdf_stamp(stamp_path, add_frame=add_frame)
    pdf_in = PdfFileReader(open(input_path, 'rb'))
    pdf_stamp = PdfFileReader(open(stamp_path, 'rb'))
    stamp = pdf_stamp.getPage(0)

    for i in xrange(pdf_in.getNumPages()):
        page = pdf_in.getPage(i)
        page.mergePage(stamp)
        output.addPage(page)

    with open(output_path, 'wb') as f:
        output.write(f)

def main():
    stamp_pdf('../input/input1.pdf', '../temp/tmp_stamp.pdf', '../output/stamped1.pdf')
    stamp_pdf('../input/input1.pdf', '../temp/tmp_stamp.pdf', '../output/stamped1_with_frame.pdf', add_frame=True)
    stamp_pdf('../input/input2.pdf', '../temp/tmp_stamp.pdf', '../output/stamped2.pdf')
    stamp_pdf('../input/input2.pdf', '../temp/tmp_stamp.pdf', '../output/stamped2_with_frame.pdf', add_frame=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":

main()
```

I'm sure there's a way to replace the individual file link so that it points directly to the directory and keeps the file name with it as well. Any pointers to get me started would be much appreciated as I have been trying out all sorts of codes without much luck.

Comment: Check out the built in pathutils library.

Comment: any chance you could give me some examples, still a bit stuck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Easily access and manage paths and filenames with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

- `pathlib` treats paths as objects instead of strings

  - `pathlib` objects have methods that work with them (e.g. `open`, `glob`, `name`, ect.)
- [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

---

### Example:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path.cwd()
print(p)
>>> WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/DataCamp')

pdf_files = list(p.glob('*.pdf'))
print(pdf_files)
>>> [WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/DataCamp/aapl.pdf')]

pdf_name = pdf_files[0].name
print(pdf_name)
>>> 'aapl.pdf'
```

- Use the `glob` method to find all the `pdf` files, including subdirectories, with `**` wildcards

  - `p.glob('**/*.pdf')`
- Use `name` to get and easily track the filename

---

### Output files:

```
out_dir = p / 'output'
print(out_dir)
>>> WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/DataCamp/output')

out_pdf = out_dir / f'stamped_{pdf_name}'
print(out_pdf)
>>> WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/DataCamp/output/stamped_aapl.pdf')
```

---

### `pythonpdf` library might not work with `pathlib` objects:

- easily convert `pathlib` objects back to `str`

```
print(type(stamp_path))
>>> pathlib.WindowsPath

print(type(str(stamp_path))
>>> str

create_pdf_stamp(str(stamp_path), add_frame=add_frame)
```

---

### iterating through `.glob`:

- The `.glob` object is a generator function

```
p = Path('e:/PythonProjects')
files = p.glob('**/*.pdf')

for file in files:
    print(file)
    ...
    # do other stuff
```

Comment: Hi @Trenton_M , thanks so much for your help, I have managed to link it to the right directory and kept the existing file name. Could you point me to the right direction for looping through all the pdf_files in the input folder?